# Visual Studio Property Window Search

Tags: visual-studio, winforms

As you know, some controls have many properties so it is difficult to find an specific property of a control in Properties window of Visual Studio. How can I search in Visual Studio Properties window?

Answer (score 2):

Select the control that you are interested in, then open the properties dialog (right-click options, or press F4) you should see a box labelled 'Search Properties'.

See image.

[image]

Comment: This works with WPF but still!! missing in VS2019 WinForms Properties panel. You need RapidDesign (paid) extension to get this feature with WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to show the search on property tap you have to install devexpress to your project and then add at least one tool from devexpress and then the "search" box will appear. I have tried it.