# Can I somehow search in Visual Studio 2017 properties window using WinForms?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Can I somehow use search in Visual Studio 2017 properties window? In Embarcadero RAD Studio there is a searchbar in properties as well as it is possible to type the first letter of property and jump to it. Is there something like this in visual studio 2017? I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34283796/10303335) answer with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itCB0.jpg) screenshot, but there is nothing like in my IDE, and I can't find an option to turn it on.

Comment: That screenshot is specific to WPF and UWP projects.  Presumably you are using Winforms, no search.  Click the toolbar buttons to switch between category grouping and alphabetic sorting.

Comment: @HansPassant Okay, thank you, if you add an answer I'll accept it :)